# Load jqGrid From Button Click

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have an aspx page where I select some input parameters, and pass them to my business logic layer from a submit button, which in turn returns data formatted for the jqGrid.  So, I don't want to display the grid when the page first loads - I want to select my parms, press submit, then display the grid.  Furthermore, I'd want to re-display the grid if different parms are selected and submit is clicked again.  I've spent the morning looking for a solution, but have not been successful.

Comment: I have some examples working with local data but in my application, the data is not available on initial page load.  I'm returning a string formatted as JSON wich comes from an arraylist.  I do this by the following code:  sJSON = serializer.Serialize( aryList ).  This is working, but I don't know how to give it to the jqGrid when I press the submit button - I'm thinking I'll use something like url: Default.aspx/GetJSON method.  I have seen more examples on how to build the grid in a function call, but I still don't understand how to call the java function from code behind.

Comment: Also, sJSON = serializer.Serialize( aryList ) doesn't give me   total: "xxx", 
  page: "yyy", 
  records: "zzz",
  rows : [
    {id:"1", cell:["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
    {id:"2", cell:["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
      ...
It just gives me rows

Comment: what did you end up doing?

Comment: I'm sorry - this was over a year ago and I don't recall what the solution was.